# How to get this tab/autocompletion setup?

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion

Basically what I want is a PyCharm-like completion:

1. If there is only whitespace, insert `<TAB>`.
2. If pum is visible and nothing is selected, complete with first, otherwise choose the selected word/function/snippet.
3. I there's any other character, go right.

Additional points:

1. Filling text with selected option from pum should be made only if I accept it. `<C-c>` or `<ESC>` should discard completion.
2. I'd like to have parentheses added if I selected class or function. If the function/class requires no arguments, place cursor after closing parentheses.

I tried getting it to work with deoplete on vim but neovim and any other plugins are also welcome.